# Connecting Java to Objective-C (using AsyncSocket)

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, sockets

I need to communicate between a Java app (desktop) and an iOS app. I've decided to use `AsyncSocket` on the iPhone side (and I've gotten data sending to work). For this question, [I'm just running the `EchoServer` demo app](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/trunk/EchoServer/AppController.m) on OSX 10.6.4. Source code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/trunk/EchoServer/AppController.m).

Here's my Java code, boiled-down:

```
    Socket echoSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.102", 8085);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println("hello there!");
    out.flush();
```

This works and the "hello there!" shows up on a TCP Monitor.

On the `EchoServer`, the output is just

```
           Accepted client 192.168.0.102:4960
```

So I know they're talking but I cannot get the data!

**Edit:** On the Java side (with more code), I do receive the Welcome to the "AsyncSocket Echo Server" message.

**Edit: If I browse to the server it works perfectly, so the problem is in my Java code. What else do I need to do for a complete write to a socket correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good clue, taken from that demo's `AppController.m`:

```
[sock readDataToData:[AsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:READ_TIMEOUT tag:0];
```

Looks like it will read a line that ends with a CR and LF. So what you might need to do on the Java side is this:

```
out.print("hello, there\r\n");
```

Or probably the same:

```
out.println("hello, there\r");
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out with no connection on a train a few hours again. I was about to delete the question, but since your answer is here and right....

Comment: the correct answer is that you NEED `\r\n\r\n`... I've tried all other combinations. I don't exactly understand this, but....